# Delegation in Swing (Python Traits Equivalent)

Tags: java, swing, traits, traitsui

I'm a long-time Python developer, and relied on Enthought's [Traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/)/TraitsUI libraries for quick GUI development.  I'm trying to understand if Swing has a similar implementation of Traits that would allow for easy delegation.

Imagine I have a JFrame that references to another class, `Foo`, and has a textfield, `fooText`.  When the user changes `fooText`, this triggers an event, and the change is propagated down to `Foo`

```
public class View extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Foo foo; 
    private javax.swing.JTextField fooText;

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    foo.fooText = this.fooText.getText();                                        

    ...
}
```

Where the `Foo`class also shares the `fooText` value:

```
public class Foo{
    public String fooText;
}
```

Is it possible to synchronize the value of `fooText` between the classes `Foo` and `View`?  In the example above, I had to manually pass the new value in through an event listener.  In the Python traits library, I can simply tell Foo to use delegation.  Something like:

```
class Foo(HasTraits):
      view = Instance(View);
      String fooText = DelegatesTo(view)
```

In this way, rather than passing shared variables, I just pass a reference to the `View` object to other objects in my program, and then any changes to `View.fooText` are immediately propagated down to the delegating classes.  This helps tremendously when UI fields need shared across many classes.

Is anything like this available in java/swing?

Thanks

Comment: In View, you declare fooText as a JTextField; in Foo, you declare fooText as a String. You can't set them equal. But in the actionListener you can set `foo.fooText = this.fooText.getText();`  (It would be better to use different names for these fields, and also better to make the text variable private in nFoo and use a Setter to set its value.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I completely overlooked the type differences.  At the end of the day, I still don't understand if they can be synchronized in the way described in TraitsUI.  I will update my question to reflect `getText()`

Comment: No, swing is not built like traits. You need to do a bit more work to expose the underlying variables.